# How can I get -drawRect to execute?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am calling a drawRect method in the UIView from a view controller class. I have the object of UIView class and I call the drawRect method using [object setNeedsDisplay]. The problem I have is when I call this function, branching to this function is not taking place. It first completes executing the function in view controller and then executes the function in UIView class. Can any one help me how to branch to UIView class and then complete viewcontroller class execution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-setNeedsDisplay just invalidates the view's rectangle. The next time the graphics system goes to draw the screen, it will ask the view to redraw itself. That's just how drawing works. In a properly constructed application, you really shouldn't care when the drawing happens. Or put another way, if you care when the drawing happens, your app probably needs some work.

If you tell us why you need drawing to occur at a specific time, perhaps we can help you work around that.

Comment: Just to add that view hierarchy is redrawn from top to bottom. Subview is redrawn after its parent view.

Comment: It might be easier to remember the order as "back to front."

Comment: In my application I draw circles for which the user can change radius. When the user changes the radius first I can clear the previously drawn circles then draw with the new radius. Here is my code   graphs_Drawing_Obj.current_Action = clearDrawingPadAction; 
 [graphs_Drawing_Obj setNeedsDisplay]; radius = new_Rad;

Comment: Don't worry about erasing the old circles -- when -drawRect: is called, you're drawing into an empty graphics context. All you need to do is to update the data in your view -- set the new radius or whatever -- and then call -setNeedsDisplay on the view. At some point the graphics system will get around to updating the display, and your view's -drawRect will be called at that point.

Comment: Its getting called my problem is in my app I will draw circle with radius 10 and then with 5. The problem comes is the circle with radius 5 over laps the circle with radius 10 because the radius 10 values is lost.

Comment: You might need to preserve some of that state, then. For example, instead of telling the view "draw circles with radius 5", you tell it "draw this array of circles" where each circle in the array has its own radius. The controller "draws" new circles by adding circle objects to the array, and removes them by deleting objects from the array.